# Missing market of high power relays?

Tags: batteries, relay, ups

Searching over the Internet for high power DC12V 100A-200A relay (to switch power on power shortage automatically from power adapter to battery) I have not found any device that is more powerful then this 30A [module](https://aliexpress.com/item/32961043558.html).

May be there is a way to adapt car relays for this purpose? Or may be any other product you can suggest?

Thank you.

Comment: Starter relays.

Comment: Contactors may be what you want?

Comment: UPSes exist so clearly these products do exist somewhere.

Comment: You're looking for 200A stuff on AliExpress? Don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling these `relays' is probably the issue. You'll need contactors and be careful of derating your contacts to the kind of load, especially if it's DC (DC arcing is harder to quench!).

Another option is, as suggested in the comments, a starter relay. In some country they are called `solenoids' which is mildly incorrect, but whatever.

These things are huge, for example the first search result weight at about 450g. They are expensive too.

Just adjust your search keyword

Comment: A starter relay would probably be designed for short term operation - just as long as it takes to start the engine - and would overheat if used for continuous operation.  I think I've seen "solenoids" similar to starter relays but rated for continuous operation.